# Bayesian multivariate regression

Tags: regression, normal-distribution, multiple-regression, multivariate-analysis, multivariate-regression

I am trying to solve the below multivariate regression problem by building a fully Bayesian model-

\begin{align*}
\mathbf{Y} = \mathbf{X}\mathbf{B} + \mathbf{E}
\end{align*}

where $\mathbf{Y} \in R^{n\times p}$ is dependent variable, $\mathbf{X} \in R^{n \times s}$ is the predictor, $\mathbf{B} \in R^{s \times p}$ stores the regression coefficients and $\mathbf{E}$ is the error term. I can use a multivariate normal distribution for $\mathbf{E}$ with mean $\mathbf{X}\mathbf{B}$ and covariance $\Sigma$, but I am not sure how to model $\mathbf{B}$. Should I use a matrix normal or multivariate normal distribution? I think matrix normal distribution will be informative but would that be overkill for the problem? This is a standard problem but I am not able to get the solution for it exactly.

Comment: E is not a parameter. It is a random vector with mean 0 and covariance matrix $\Sigma$. You need a prior for $\Sigma$; inverse Wishart works. For $\beta$ you can use multivariate normal with some anticipated mean vector, and with a covariance matrix having large variances so as to be realistically vague.